WebStorm Code Style Don't Force Object Initialization to New Line
I'm trying to use the WebStorm code style configurations to establish team style enforcement.  I'm getting close but can't figure out what setting needs to be adjusted.  I want to have my code look like this:
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                DisplayWidgetService, 
                { provide: LogService, useValue: logServiceSpy },
                { provide: DataStoreService, useValue: dataStoreServiceSpy },
                { provide: WorkFlowManagerService, useValue: workFlowManagerServiceSpy }, 
                { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy }
            ]
        })

But after my reformat rules apply I get this:
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                DisplayWidgetService, { provide: LogService, useValue: logServiceSpy }, {
                    provide: DataStoreService,
                    useValue: dataStoreServiceSpy
                }, { provide: WorkFlowManagerService, useValue: workFlowManagerServiceSpy }, {
                    provide: MatDialog,
                    useValue: dialogSpy
                }]
        })

What rules/settings should I be looking at so that the object initialization in TS/JS aren't forced to a new line like this?
